# Find and Replace SPSS Syntax

Tags: syntax, spss

I'm looking to Find and Replace in SPSS but ideally using syntax, not the CTRL+F.

And I need it for something fairly specific. I have a dataset with 100 variables.
In all variables, I want to search for any cell that says "na" and replace it with just "" (a blank).

But I dont want any instance of "na", for example in the word "Anna", I just want if the entire contents of the cell says "na" make the cell "" instead.

How can I achieve this with syntax for all columns in the dataset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to delete every instance of "na" within the text this would do it:

```
do repeat vr=yourfirstvar to yourlastvar.
compute vr=replace(vr, "na", "").
end repeat.
```

If on the other hand you want to replace only when the full value is "na" use this instead:

```
recode all ("na"="").
```

Note: both answers here assume all your variables are text and not numeric. If you have both types mixed together you should put the variable names in the command instead of `all`, or use `varX to varY` if they are text variables and are contiguous in the dataset.